# Using S3 only in production Django

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage

I have my base_settings.py set to `DEBUG = False`, at the end of my settings I have the following code:

```
    if not DEBUG:
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket_name'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
    S3_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
    STATIC_URL = S3_URL
```

In my local_settings.py I have set `DEBUG = True`.

My **init**.py file for settings module:

```
from .base import *

try:
    from .local import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

For some reason, when working in locally, it still tries to pull static files out of S3 despite my if not DEBUG setting. The reason I am thinking of is that it is reading the base file first and testing DEBUG before the local_settings.py is actually imported. So my question is: How do I go around this so s3 files are only used on production?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a .local package locally, try removing the try/except around the .local import and see if any errors are thrown.

Also, if are you setting DEBUG in base as TRUE, and the setting your URLS and storages, and then setting DEBUG to false in .locals, you you need to reset your URLS and storages in .locals.

.locals are imported AFTER your base file has already been imported, so your line:

```
if not DEBUG:
```

…evalutes to TRUE during import, sets everything up to use S3.